# How to define React Navigation navigationOptions parameter in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

In a React Native app using React Navigation, I have a screen component, where I want to define the `title` using the `navigationOptions` property based on the given parameters, like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.myParam
});
```

It works fine, and the title is printed correctly.
However, now I'm migrating the app to Typescript, and I want to define `myParam` as a required string, and I don't know how to define the parameter so I get autocompletion in my IDE:

```
({navigation}: /* WhatDoIPutHere? */)
```

I tried the approach in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/martinemmert/70661f6b363367bc8eceb981965b997a), but as I commented myself in there, that's not working fine for me...

What's the correct type I can use to define the expected parameters there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually the solution in [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/martinemmert/70661f6b363367bc8eceb981965b997a) I linked from the question is almost correct - the problem is just `navigation.state.params` might be undefined according to the definition! So, Typescript and my IDE (smart guys) were complaining about it...

You can see the relevant bit from the definitions [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/88fc0023e634a69f12b1e58e98ffd580c51e7f54/types/react-navigation/index.d.ts#L100):

```
export interface NavigationLeafRoute<Params> {
  // ...
  /**
   * Params passed to this route when navigating to it,
   * e.g. `{ car_id: 123 }` in a route that displays a car.
   */
  params?: Params;
}
```

So I ended up doing this in my component:

```
interface Params {
    myParam: string
}

// ...

static navigationOptions = ({navigation}: NavigationScreenProps<Params>) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.myParam : 'Default title'
});
```

And it works nicely, including autocompletion in my IDE - starting to like Typescript a lot!

Comment: It also provides type checking if you use `navigation.getParam()`. (you can only use keys which are properties in your `Params` interface)

Comment: typescript really force you to write Fail-safe code.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

```
import { NavigationScreenProp, NavigationRoute } from 'react-navigation';

interface Params {
  otherId: string;
  otherName: string;
  otherPic: string;
  id: string;
}

class MessengerContainer extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: { navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationRoute<Params>, Params>}) => ({

// ... more code here

});
```